# Загрузка картинки на сервер через POST-запрос

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Третий день бьюсь с отправкой картинкой на сервер. Не использую сторонних библиотек.
Нужно отправить картинку на сервер с параметров 'avatar'

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 90);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my-url.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSString *boundary = @"----FOO";
NSString *filename = @"latest_photo.png";

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:imageData];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];
```

Беру картинку, переделываю ее в NSData. Составляю сам запрос. Формирую тело пост-запроса(контент-тайпы, баундари вроде все прописано)

Нужно отправить картинку с параметром 'avatar'. Вопрос: где нужно прописать этот параметр? Спасибо:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что вы имеете в виду под картинкой с параметром avatar? Это явно не какой-то стандартный способ, а особенность вашего хоста. Тут скорее всего одно из двух, либо хост принимает картинки в виде avatar=<ваша картинка либо через сырые данные, либо, что скорее, в  base64>, либо это путь на хосте для специфического скрипта приема и урл должен быть вида http://my-url.com/avatar, а данные просто передаются в теле запроса. В любом случае надо смотреть как это обрабатывается на сервере, точнее без этого не скажешь.

Кроме того, вы (или тот кто писал сервер) что-то перемудрили с телом и заголовками запроса, как минимум вот этот кусок (и подобный ему с `Content-Disposition:`) очень странный `[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` - всю жизнь был хедером, вы даже его повторно описываете ниже еще раз как хедер, да и наличие конца строки тоже разделение хедеров, а два конца строки - это отделения заголовков от тела.

Резюмируя, на ваш вопрос в данном виде нельзя дать ответ, непонятно что собственно нужно серверу и что вы хотели сделать, если у вас есть описание АПИ сервера - приведите его

Comment: спасибо за комментарий! Просто в интернете у каждого свой способ отправки картинки на сервер, что все это у меня перемешалось в кашу:(

Вопрос: я могу использовать метод setHttpBody 2 раза? Один для того, чтобы прикрепить к запросу картинку, а второй для того чтобы отправитьсам параметр "avatar".

Comment: насколько понимаю, нет, 2 раза не выйдет - это стандартный сеттер, он просто переписывает ивар Body